# Software firewall with "zone files"

Tags: configuration, firewall, deployment

I am using an automatic deployment system for my new Unix deployments.  I have a fairly complicated network topology to implement, and I'm looking for firewall software that makes this easy.

In particular, I have noticed that software like nginx follows a pattern in which the main configuration file loads a wildcard, which effectively loads all of the files in some directory.

So, for example, nginx loads all of the files in /etc/nginx/conf/ and treats them as configuration files.  They can be loaded and unloaded independently by adding or removing them (and issuing an nginx command).

Are there any trusted software firewall products that let me do something similar?

Answer (score 1):

If you already use firewall software that fulfils its purpose and that you know how to use, but lacks this facility, I suggest you stick with it.

The switch from, or addition to, an application using a single configuration file to a directory whose file contents are taken combined to be the configuration, is often made because of package maintainability. Configuration options in a single file are much harder to update/change and it is difficult for additional (third party) options to insert themselves without breaking that possibility for others that they don't know about.
Once there were multiple working examples, more and more software started using this model.

If your preferred firewall software doesn't support this feature yet, it is however relatively easy to emulate, by splitting up the contents of your firewall configuration into discrete parts and using `cat` to concatenate them into one file that can be used by the firewall. Give the individual filenames the form of XY_NAME, where XY is some number and NAME a descriptive name. Increment XY in steps of 5 or 10, so you have some space to insert files in between at a later stage. Just use:

```
cat * > ../firewall.cfg
```

and the number part of the name makes sure the order of files being processed is deterministic. If the configuration file doesn't support comments in a way you like ( XML comes to mind ), you can use those in the XY_NAME files and filter them out during the combination process e.g. using `grep -v '^#'`